# How to use query option into aws-sdk-go?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk-go

I'm trying to use AWS SDK Go to create an AutoScaling Group.

I'd like to run the following aws cli to make sure I get the unused ones from the pre-allocated EIPs, but I'm not sure how to express `--query` to get the same behavior

```
aws ec2 describe-addresses --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=sample-value" --query "Addresses[?AssociationId==\`null\`].AllocationId"
```

I would like to simply select the ones that do not have `AssociationId` assigned from the retrieved array, but is it possible to filter them programmatically?

It specifies such an Input.

```golang
input := &ec2.DescribeAddressesInput{
        Filters: []*ec2.Filter{
            {
                Name: aws.String("tag:Name"),
                Values: []*string{
                    aws.String("sample-value"),
                },
            },
        },
    }
```

thanks

Comment: The `--query` option is local to the awscli client. It's client-side, not part of the EC2 API. You'd have to implement the same locally in Go.

Comment: @jarmod Thanks !!
I couldn't think of a good way to implement it.
It is now possible to retrieve the ones whose AssociationId is null from the retrieved array by loop processing.
I don't think this is a good idea and I was wondering if you had any suggestions?

Comment: Why is it not a good idea? I don't think you have an alternative. The `--filters` (server-side filtering) option does not seem to have any way to indicate associationId absent/null/empty (that I can find anyway).